# Group by in LINQ with 2 attributes

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

This is an already asked question, but [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq) is to work with 2 attributes only, I need to work with 3 attributes, So I am copy-pasting most of the text.

Let's suppose if we have a class like

```
class Person { 
internal int PersonID; 
internal string car  ;
internal string friend  ;
}
```

Now I have a list of this class: List persons;

Now this list can have instances multiple same PersonIDs, for ex.

```
persons[0] = new Person { PersonID = 1, car = "Ferrari" , friend = "Josh" }; 
persons[1] = new Person { PersonID = 1, car = "BMW" , friend = "Olof"     }; 
persons[2] = new Person { PersonID = 2, car = "Audi"  , friend = "Gustaf"   };
```

Is there a way I can group by PersonID and get the list of all the cars and friends he has? For example the expected result would be:

```
class Result { 
   int PersonID;
   List<string> cars; 
   List<string> friends; 
}
```

From what I have done so far:

```
IEnumerable resultsForDisplay = ResultFromSQL_Query.GroupBy(
    p => p.PersonId.ToString(),
    p => p.car,
    (key,  g) => new { PersonId = key, car = g.ToList()});
```

But now I'm stuck at getting the `friend's` array in `resultsForDisplay`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can perform LINQ queries on the group `g` as well, like:

```
IEnumerable<Result> resultsForDisplay = from q in ResultFromSQL_Query
    group q by q.PersonID into g
    select new Result {PersonID = g.Key,cars = g.Select(x => x.car).ToList(), friends = g.Select(x => x.friend).ToList()};
```

Or with *lambda expressions*:

```
IEnumerable<Result> results = persons.GroupBy(x => x.PersonID)
    .Select(g => new Result { PersonID = g.Key, cars = g.Select(x => x.car).ToList(), friends = g.Select(x => x.friend).ToList()};
```

So you can perform any LINQ query on a group (which thus behaves as an `IEnumerable<>` on the elements of that grou), like a `.Select(..)`, but also `.Sum(..)`, `.Average(..)` and other *sub queries*, *aggregates*, etc.

Comment: Hi, please forgive me, but im a newbie in Linq and Lambda expression. Could you please convert this syntax to lambda expression?

Comment: Also, when i try to use your syntax, it gives me an error on `Result` in line `select new Result { `
the error says 
`The type or namespace name 'Result' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @AtifWaqar: yes, these have to be written on a single line I think.

Comment: @AtifWaqar: `Result` is a class in your question. If you haven't got a proper reference to it then only you can answer why that is. Are you missing a using directive perhaps? Or did you just not put the class in your code and just in the question?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem This is Amazing. I was stuck at this for a long time. Thanks you very much for the solution :) 

About `Result`, I got it, its the returning data type.